# Dealing with Lots of 0s (Zeroes) in Timeseries Dataframe using Pycaret

Tags: time-series

Business only collects data during business working (Monday to Saturday from **08h00 to 16h00** and Sundays from **08h00 to 13h00**). Data is collected every **30 minutes **(Frequency).

**How can I best deal with 0s (Zeroes) that are recorded outside business hours?.**

I have tried specifying Business, deleting Non Business Hours, Resampling, and Log transformation but the Models seems to perform worse since it interpret deleted non business hours as missing data

Comment: We need more technical information.  Where is this data being stored?  Is this going into a MySQL database?  What version , etc.

Comment: The data is already stored in SQL Database.

Comment: Pure SQL ? Dang I can help with MySQL situations.  Also can we see the line of code that is "dealing with the 0's" so we can upgrade it to do something differently with its formula?  I assume maybe if you can convert the 0 into NULL that would send NOTHING, so it might be okay, UNLESS your code is EXPECTING it to be an Integer, and since its NOTHING its converting to 0 before insert.